# Combining Hex string

Tags: c, hex

I am working on a C program where I have been given 91 bits of an AES Key and need to iterate through the other possible 37 to get a full key. In hex, the key looks like this where the F's is the unknown part of the key.

FF FF FF FF FC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03

When iterating through the unknown portion, I will obviously need to combine the unknown portion to the known portion. Being I have an odd number of 9 bytes that need to be found, how will I combine that last byte to the "C" to ensure I get the correct length key?

Comment: How do you plan to store your `key`?

Comment: As a "const static unsigned char"

Comment: Then you can use `AND` to remove (drop to zero) certain bits and `OR` to give them a new value.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways that you could do it, but I would do it this way:

1. Initialize four 128-bit values, `min`, `max`, `inc`, and `base`. Set `min` to zero. Set `max` to FF FF FF FF F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00. Set `base` to the given key with zeroes in all the spots that are unknown. Set `inc` to 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00.
2. Loop from `min` to `max` adding `inc` each time. For each entry, OR the current loop index with `base`. That's the value you test.